# Find another function from a current function but with another zero/root

Tags: functions, computational-complexity

Not sure if anyone can understand the title (my math vocab/basics are lacking), but basically this:

Given a specific function that has a certain number of a specific set of zeros, I want to be able to find another function that has all of the same zeros, but with another zero added to the function.

An example would be something like, given a function with the roots 1 and 3, say I wanted to find another function with the same roots but with the added root 22. Also, would this be possible backwards? If I have a function with the roots 1,3,22, would I be able to find one with roots 1 and 3 using the previous function?

How costly would this be from a time complexity stance?

Thanks!

Comment: If $f(x)$ has roots 1 and 3, then $g(x):=(x-22)f(x)$ has ... ?

Comment: And going the other way is just as easy. If $f(x)$ has $1$, $3$ and $22$ as roots (with multiplicity 1), $g(x)=f(x)/(x-22)$ (patched to be defined at $x=22$ (where it has a removable singularity)) $\ldots$

Comment: duh, that makes sense. thanks!